# Create user to monitor database activity on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, monitoring

Postgres 9.3
Debian 7

I want to create a monitor user called monitor that the only permission is to run queries to monitor all the database activity.
I created the user and it can select from pg_stat_activity, the problem is that it only sees it's own activity and I want this user to see all users activity.

Is there any special privilege to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, only superusers can see others' activity details in pg_stat_activity.

PostgreSQL could use a finer-grained rights model, where you can `GRANT` the `MONITOR_QUERIES` right to a user, for example. But right now it doesn't have one, and quite a few things are superuser-only. This is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a normal user and provide the default `pg_monitor` role to get all monitoring metrics. Simple two steps:

Create a user:

```
CREATE USER db_monitor WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Grant the role to monitor:

```
GRANT pg_monitor TO db_monitor;
```

`pg_monitor`:

- This role read/execute various monitoring views and functions.
- Its is a combination of pg_read_all_settings, pg_read_all_stats and
  pg_stat_scan_tables roles

Comment: Is this a new feature? Do you know what version it was included?

Comment: Currently i use them in latest postgresql version v13 but i believe this feature is available from `postgresql v10`

Comment: I am using v14.11; doing the query `select * from pg_stat_all_tables
where schemaname = 'public';` returns nothing for this db_monitor user, whereas the owner of the database can get good results;